# How can i test my TSQL syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010

Quick question: How do I get some kind of database to use to test my SQL syntax and create basic data.

---

I have Sqlite Code which I'll soon put on a server. I have SQL Server 2008 installed with visual studio 2010. I tried connecting to the database and [had no luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851882/how-do-i-use-sql-server-2008-with-visual-studios).

I also tried using an .mdf file instead thinking it's a file and I won't have connectivity issues. Wrong, I still couldn't connect and I used [this site to help me](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005) (i'm aware its 2005)

In that case I used:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\dev\src\test\SQL_DB_VS_Test\test.mdf;Database=dbo;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");
```

exception

```
Unable to open the physical file "C:\dev\src\test\SQL_DB_VS_Test\test.mdf". 
Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".
Cannot attach the file 'C:\dev\src\test\SQL_DB_VS_Test\test.mdf' as database 'dbo'.
```

With trusted = no I get `Login failed for user ''.` (What user am I suppose to set?). I created the .mdf with Visual Studio somehow.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/9e563890-e35f-4524-82b9-3cca08fec5ed

Comment: Have you tried opening the database using SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating the mdf file with visual studios right click the mdf and select properties. In it you'll see a row called Connection String. Copy/paste it into your app and it should connect. The key part is `User Instance=True`

Answer (score 1):

What if you try this connection string:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLExpress;
        AttachDbFilename=C:\dev\src\test\SQL_DB_VS_Test\test.mdf;
        Database=test;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
```

I don't think it's a good idea to call your database "dbo" (that's a SQL Server keyword - I wouldn't use it for my own purposes!), and also I believe you need to use `Integrated Security=SSPI;` to define Windows authentication - Trusted_Connection is not used for SQL Server connection strings, AFAIK.

Comment: I didnt call it that. Visual studio made it. I am just trying to access the database somehow. After two hours with trying it and non mdf files i figured out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [SSMS](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en) to access your local instance?  It's helpful for getting connected and getting everything setup.  Also, I think the default install of Sql Express with VS only support trusted connections.